# Wondering why I'm getting a syntax error with this python code definition

Tags: python

```
def validateInput(uChoice):
    #function to validate user choice
    if  uChoice  == "rock" or uChoice  == "paper" or uChoice  == "scissors" or uChoice  == "lizard" or uChoice  == "spock
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: And also a double quote is missing before return True: uChoice == "spock"

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that you're missing the double quote to end `"spock`

Comment: You can replace the whole function with `return uChoice in ('rock','paper','scissors','lizard','spock')`

Comment: Looks like the `if` needs to have a colon at the end of it, too.

Comment: Thanks Tim that's such a better way to do it, I also fixed with adding a colon.

Answer (score 1):

You missed `:` at the end of the `if` statement and close the last string. Your code should be:

```
def validateInput(uChoice):
    #function to validate user choice
    if uChoice == "rock" or uChoice == "paper" or uChoice == "scissors" or uChoice == "lizard" or uChoice == "spock":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

---

In terms of better understanding of the code, it would be better if you use a container (as a list) and check the belonging of `uChoice` to it. That is,

```
def validateInput(uChoice):
    return uChoice in ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "spock"]
```

Comment: One might even use a set rather than a list.

Comment: Yes, a container or iterable as a set, list, tuple, etc.